# Array comparision always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an application where array comparison is required .

HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" id="cData" value="0,3,2,0,0,0">
```

JQ :

```
var lblArr = [];
var attrArray = $("#cData").val();
lblArr = attrArray.split(',');
$.each(attrArray, function(i) {
  lblArr.push(attrArray[i]);
});

console.log("LBL Array       * " + lblArr);

var llblArr = [0,3,2,0,0,0];

console.log("LLLBL Array     * " + llblArr);

var array1 = lblArr;
var array2 = llblArr;

var is_same = array1.length == array2.length && array1.every(function(element, index) {
return element === array2[index];
});

console.log(is_same);
```

I am always getting false .Any suggestions ??

Comment: First read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Be nice with him. We see much worse formatted questions all day long, this one is not so bad ;)

Comment: @JeremyThille : Thanks for some nice words :)  hindmost : I will improve on next time onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert data in array `attrArray` from `String` To `Number`, like so

```
lblArr = attrArray.split(',');
lblArr = $.map(attrArray.split(','), function(el) {
   return +el; 
   // to convert string to number you can also use 
   // return parseInt(el, 10); 
   // or 
   // return Number(el); 
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/moxawu/1/edit?js,output#J:L4)

because you have two arrays one of them looks like this `["0","3","2","0","0","0"]` and second `[0,3,2,0,0,0]` and you compare `"0"` with `0` it will be false because you use `===` (strict equals operator). You can change it to `==` (Equals Operator) and don't use `parseInt`, like so

```
var is_same = array1.length == array2.length && array1.every(function(element, index) {
   return element == array2[index];
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/moxawu/2/edit?js,console)

[Difference between == and ===](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/)